# Convergence of triangle function to a constant

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Consider a real valued function $f$  with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/n)=1$ which is linear on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ everywhere else. Does $f$ converge pointwise to $0$?

Specifically im trying to understand the behavior at $0$. The value at $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity seems illdefined.

Comment: Yes, $f$ converges pointwise to $0$. The sequence of values at $0$ is, by definition, the constant sequence with constant value $0$, which converges to $0$; what is the problem?

Comment: The limit of the location of the peak is 0. So while $f(0)=0$ for all $n$, i expect the limit is undefined at this point.

Comment: $f_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent to $f(x)$ if  $$lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$$
The convergence of $f_n(0)$ is independent of the values of $f_n(x)$ where $x \neq 0$